# Why was my question better suited to Super User than here?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I was wondering why [my post](https://superuser.com/questions/268470/clear-drop-down-history-of-firefox) was migrated to Super User?

Generally, what kinds of web application questions belong here and what belong to Super User?

Comment: also http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq may be of interest, the what to ask section is right at the top

Answer (score 10):

Web Applications aren't installed on your computer and tend to run only in your browser.

Your question was about how to configure Firefox, which is a program that is installed on your computer. This is the domain of Super User.

Firefox is not a web app and hence questions about it are generally suited to the site that does deal with software and hardware issues like that.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering where Web Applications are installed?

Comment: Generally they run inside your browser and are installed on someone else's server or computer. @tim